# Visual Basic For Excel

Tags: excel, visual

Aquí mi primera pregunta:

Estoy desarrollando una macro en Excel, mediante el modo grabación
Este es el código resultante:

```
Sub GENERARSIMAT()

Workbooks.Add
Windows("macros1").Activate
Sheets("Compilado").Select
Columns("A:Y").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Libro2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Sheets("Hoja1").Name = "SIMAT"
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ChDir "D:my dir"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:my dir\SIMAT.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Windows("macros1").Activate
Sheets("MACROS").Select
```

End Sub

El contexto es el siguiente: cuando corro la macro para generar un nuevo archivo, dependo del consecutivo que en el momento tenga, y lo que quiero eliminar es ese consecutivo, como pueden ver Windows("Libro2").Activate depende de que el libro donde se va a pegar la información que llevo se llame libro2, existe alguna forma que no dependa de ese numero consecutivo?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: This website is for question in spanish.

Comment: @Diego veo que revertiste la modificación que había hecho... Un título así no ayuda a especificar tu pregunta. Además, se recomiendo no usar saludos ni agradecimientos: directo al grano para que sea más resumido y fácil de leer. Además, deberías etiquetarla como [tag:vba] (Visual Basic para Aplicaciones), y eliminar la etiqueta "visual"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
Dim NuevoLibro As Workbook
Set NuevoLibro = Workbooks.Add

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compilado").Columns("A:Y").Copy
NuevoLibro.ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Paste
NuevoLibro.Worksheets(1).Name = "SIMAT"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ChDir "D:my dir"
NuevoLibro.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "D:my dir\SIMAT.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MACROS").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks.Add` te devuelve la referencia al nuevo libro. La idea es usar ese valor devuelto, sin intentar adivinar el nombre.

```
'COPIAR DESDE ...

'Copiar desde la hoja Compilado - todo el rango usado
Sheets("Compilado").UsedRange.Copy

'PEGAR VALORES EN ...

'Crear un nuevo Libro
Dim nuevoLibro As WorkBook
Set nuevoLibro = Workbooks.Add    'Acá obtenemos la referencia al nuevo libro

'Obtener la 1ra hoja
Dim primeraHoja As WorkSheet
Set primeraHoja = nuevoLibro.Sheets(1)

'Pegar lo que hayas copiado antes
primeraHoja.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Olvidarse de lo que esté copiado en el clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Cambiarle el nombre a la hoja
primeraHoja.Name = "SIMAT"

'Guardar el libro
nuevoLibro.SaveAs Filename:= "D:my dir\SIMAT.xlsx
```

Comment: Probé dejando esto en el principio del código 
Dim nuevoLibro As WorkBook
Set nuevoLibro = Workbooks.Add 
y no me funciono, tambien cambie libro2 por nuevoLibro.

Comment: @DiegoM jajaja la idea es que tomes el código y lo adaptes, intentando entender qué hace... ahí edité la respuesta para que te sea más sencillo